# Dateparser date parsing strange issue

Tags: python, date-parsing

dateparser.parse("03 AUGUST 2018, 00:26 AM IST")

Try parsing the above date with dateparser. I have been using dateparser from 3 months, I choose these module because it supports multi languge. But I have faced something strange today. It could parse anything but not this. I have changed the months, but no luck. Can anyone say, why is this? how to approach to solve the problem? It works only when I remove "AM/PM" from this kind of format.

Comment: Is that [the dateparser for Python](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser)?

Comment: yeah, dateparser for python @OleV.V.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this format is false, you are writing in 24-hour format (from 0 to 23) where there is no AM/PM. If you want add AM/PM so you have to go with the 12hour format ( from 1 to 12, with AM/PM)

Check this [table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)

Comment: Thanks, I thought these things can be ignored by default by the parsers